# You are attempting to open a precompiled Web site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a website developed in asp.net. Files have both aspx pages and codebehind files. When I try to open it in Visual studio 2010, I get this message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
You are attempting to open a precompiled Web site. You can view the site, but changes might cause the Web site to stop functioning. To modify a site, it is recommended that you edit the files in the original Web site, precompile the site, and then publish it again.

Do you wish to continue and open this Web site?
---------------------------
Yes   No
```

---

How to open this website for editting ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is WAY late but it might be of use to subsequent readers.

First off, Martuza Kabul is wrong. You only need 2 files, the .aspx/.ascx/.master and the relevant .cs (this means .aspx.cs/.ascx.cs/.master.cs)

What has most likely happened here is that somebody has compiled the site and the DLLs are now lying in the bin folder. (If you are as lucky as i am, they're also in source control..)

Here's what you need to do:

- Delete the PrecompiledApp.config file
- Delete all the non library .dll files in your bin folder (mine were WebApp_122141Xas or something like that, these are compiled codebehind files.)
- Look at the first line of your .aspx / .ascx pages - In that control tag - in there is an "inherits" attribute... you will see it has 2 values, delete the 2nd one.
- In that same control tag, notice that the Codefile attribute is missing. Add it and point it to the correct codebehind file.

That should be it. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have CS file to edit the website. I assume that you are trying to open a website which was published earlier using precompiled option.

Pls post type of files in your website for further information.

Comment: @Murtaza: I have aspx pages and aspx.cs files and web.config files

Comment: you also need the .cs files. The aspx.cs files are designer files and not codebehind files

Comment: For each page you need three files - 1. aspx, 2 aspx.cs and 3 cs - to edit the project, and as I said, I'm now sure that you are trying to open a published site.

Comment: just try to remove PrecompiledApp.config if you have it.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. It worked when i removed precompiledApp.config but now getting errors like this: c:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Temp\3\Temporary ASP.NET Files\abc.com\69c025ae\cae49379\App_Web_4guys.master.cdcab7d2.uhy0xtxd.0.cs(221): error CS0433: The type 'ProfileCommon' exists in both 'c:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Temp\3\Temporary ASP.NET Files\abc.com\69c025ae\cae49379\assembly\dl3\6b632b43\00ff4257_ca95c801\App_Code.DLL' and 'c:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Temp\3\Temporary ASP.NET Files\flsdev.fctcompanies.com\69c025ae\cae49379\App_Code.q27am0of.dll'

Comment: maybe remove files for this site in Temporary ASP.NET?

Comment: @Alex: I removed but still same error. same error like this: http://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/solving-the-profilecommon-ambiguous-error/

Comment: did you try solution from this post?

Comment: but I don't think it's related to problem, that site was precompiled

Comment: I mean you can ask this as another question and maybe somebody will help you

Comment: Try to search for any cs file in the website folder. (not aspx.cs). If you do not find one, you are out of luck. From the error it appears that you have pre-compiled dlls and not the source cs files.